# Watch and OCR convert new PDFs inside a Folder to a searchable pdf

Tags: windows, automation, ocr

My scanner automatically puts the PDFs inside a network folder. I would love to have that folder searchable. Therefore, I am searching for a tool that watches the Folder and automatically converts a new coming PDF inside the folder with OCR to a searchable PDF.

I know there is e.g. [OCRmyPDF](https://github.com/ocrmypdf/OCRmyPDF) but it is too complicated to install on windows. And Tesseract itself only works with images and not pdfs.